# API Response extract the value - Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml, api, groovy

I'm receiving the below response from API (GET Method)

```
{
   "time" : "0.000143",
   "status" : "success",
   "family" : {
      "members" : [
         "FS-40902",
         "FS-40903",
         "ES-100",         
      ],
      "_dwh_time" : "0.023569",
      "family_id" : 251653,
      "root" : "AR-1386-A2"
   }
}
```

Below is the code

```
String familyXML = response.getResponseText()
def xmlResult = new XmlSlurper().parseText(familyXML)
def familyMembersList = xmlResult.family.members[1].text()
```

When I'm executing the above code getting the below issue

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

My expectation - I want to extract all the values in the "`family members" section.

Comment: you are trying to.parse JSON as XML.

Comment: @collapsar I thought the output response format is XML so that I use xmlSlurper if anything wrong please correct me.

Comment: Use the JSonSlurper. Or first look up XML and JSON in Wikipedia. Sorry for the incredulous tone but it really feels like a prank, from someone having 2000+ reputation in Stackoverflow.